# Map an Entity iEnumerator To Dto Enumerator

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, ienumerable, dto

I am using CQRS. I select my Entities IEnumerator from database and i want to map this to my Dto class.

My Dto class:

```
public class XCollectionDto
{
    public IEnumerable<XReadDto> Entries { get; init; } = Enumerable.Empty<XReadDto>();
}
```

My mapper class:

```
public class XReadMapper : IEntityToDtoMapper<X, XCollectionDto>
{
    public XCollectionDto Map(IEnumerable <X> source, XCollectionDto target)
    {
        //todo

        Here i want to map source to target Entries list
    }
}
```

How can i do that, without a for loop? I am not using AutoMaper, the mapping is manual

Comment: What is `target`? Is this method supposed to return a value or update the one passed in?

Comment: But essentially you are looking for something like this, right? `return new XCollectionDto { Entries = source.Select(x => new XReadDto { ... }) };`

Comment: target is suposed to return just an list of object , its a Dto. In order to not return my database model, i want to return the dto model. It also doesn't have all the properties the database model has

Comment: @DavidG yes, something like that, but i don't want to create a new XCollectionDto . I have to fill the target.Entries i receive as parameter

Answer (score 1):

I think you could  accompish your purpose with C# reflection

I created the two class for test:

```
public class somemodel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<int> Numlist { get; set; }
    }

 public class somemodelDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SomeName { get; set; }
        public List<int> Numlist { get; set; }
    }
```

the method to bind properties  of  somemodelDTO which have the same name with  properties  of somemodel:

```
private static somemodelDTO GetMap<somemodel, somemodelDTO>(somemodel some)
        {
            somemodelDTO somemDTO = Activator.CreateInstance<somemodelDTO>();
            var typesource = some.GetType();
            var typedestination = typeof(somemodelDTO);
            foreach(var sp in typesource.GetProperties())
            {
                foreach( var dp in typedestination.GetProperties())
                {
                     if(sp.Name==dp.Name)
                    {
                        dp.SetValue(somemDTO, sp.GetValue(some, null), null);
                    }
                }
            }
            return somemDTO;
        }
```

The result：
[image]
[image]